# How to Automate Identity with specific App Id using Pulumi

Tags: pulumi

I'm trying to automate the following screen using Pulumi

[image: Identity]

I have my own App ID.

The current WebApp `identity` property does not match this screen:

```js
const dotnetApp = new web.WebApp("apitesterapp", {
  resourceGroupName: Config.ResourceGroup,
  serverFarmId: plan.id,
  kind: "FunctionApp",
  siteConfig: {
      appSettings: [
          { name: "runtime", value: "dotnet" },
          { name: "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME", value: "dotnet" },
          { name: "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE", value: dotnetBlobSignedURL },
          { name: "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION", value: "~3" },
      ],
  }, 
  identity: {
    type: "SystemAssigned"
  }
});
```

I'm thinking of doing an extra step using Powershell, but I wanted to try out doing 100% Pulumi if possible.

Comment: What is the Powershell command that does this?

Comment: I don't think there's a Powershell command to do this, but this seems like the thing I would use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updateauthsettings

Comment: Yup, it's not in Az Module as of yet https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/12563 

But some `az account get-access-token` and calling that endpoint seems like a real possibility

Comment: I might get away with doing something with execSync on Pulumi